# How can i prove the following implications?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, asymptotics

Let $d_n=lcm(1,2,...,n)$ and $x_n$ be a sequence of positive real numbers.Let $\{x\}$ be the fractional part of x. Consider the following propositions:

$i)$ $\displaystyle\limsup_{n \to \infty} t^n \{log (x_n)\}>0 $  for some positive number $t<(4/e)^2$.

$ii)$ $\{log (x_n)\} \neq (e/4)^{2n(1+o(1))}$.

$iii)$ $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} 
\frac{4^{2n}}{d_{2n}} \{log (x_n)\} \neq \frac{\pi}{6log(2)} $.

knowing that $d_n = e^{n(1+o(1))}$, how can i prove that $i) \Rightarrow ii)  \Rightarrow iii)$  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can prove the contrapositives of these implications as follows. Suppose ii) is false, that is $\{\log (x_n)\} =(e/4)^{2n(1+o(1))}$. Now suppose $t < (4/e)^2$. Then there is an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\sqrt{t}e/4 = 1-\epsilon$, and we have $t^n\{\log (x_n)\} = (\sqrt{t}e/4)^{2n(1+o(1)} = (1-\epsilon)^{2n(1+o(1))} \rightarrow 0$, so i) is false.

Similarly, if iii) is false, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} 
\frac{4^{2n}}{d_{2n}} \{\log (x_n)\} = \frac{\pi}{6log(2)}$. Plugging $d_n = e^{n(1+o(1))}$ into this, we get $\{\log (x_n)\} = (e/4)^{2n}\frac{\pi}{6log(2)} = (e/4)^{2n(1+o(1))}$, so ii) is false.